# I cannot install the package tcltk in R

Tags: r, linux, tcltk

I'm trying to install the package `Rcmdr` however it has a dependency on `tcltk2` whom has a dependency on `tcltk` but I cannot install `tcltk`.

My status:

```
> capabilities()["tcltk"]
tcltk 
FALSE
```

What I've tried:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tcltk/tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)
```

Returns:

> Installing package into ‘/home/felipeaugustox/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tcltk/tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5000 bytes
> ==================================================
> downloaded 5000 bytes

> ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘/tmp/RtmpH9kH6v/downloaded_packages/tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpH9kH6v/downloaded_packages/tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

What I also tried:

```
R CMD INSTALL tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz
```

Returns:

> ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz’

My setup:

- R version 3.6.1
- Ubuntu 18.06

Comment: tcltk is a system package. Look up on AskUbuntu how to install it.

Comment: @IRTFM I installed with `sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev`

Comment: In that case perhaps using a binary install of the R package, making sure that it is matched to R 3.6.x. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Isn't that what I tried? `R CMD INSTALL tcltk_0.1-1.tar.gz`

Comment: @user20650 After that: `r-cran-tcltk2 is already the newest version (1.2-11-1.1).`

Comment: I thought the tar.gz packages were source rather than binary. I'm not an expert. I just installed that package from an Rstudio console and see: after snipping the installation messages which did NOT indicate that this needed compilation `"* DONE (tcltk2)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpzcDvH5/downloaded_packages’
> library(tcltk2)`
Loading required package: tcltk" I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and R 3.6.1 My suystem reports `$ echo "puts [info tclversion]" | tclsh #
8.6`

Comment: I’m wondering if there is a conflict or confusion about which version of tcl is being accessed by R. Supposedly R ships with tcltk 8.5

Comment: I read in some place that I needed to "build from source with tcltk installed", but I don't know what it means, since I could achieve what I want without this package I'm gonna stop searching for a solution, but keep the question, for other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is what one user found successful:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/itcl3/itcl3_3.4.3-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./itcl3_3.4.3-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I installed here, but I receive the same errors when trying to install `tcltk2`:  > error: Tcl/Tk support is not available on this system